# Configure Parameters using gin-config and importlib

Tags: python, python-importlib

I am using gin-config to configure the hyperparameters of different classes. This is working perfectly fine for modules that are imported the classical way. However, how to configure a parameter, used in a class that is imported using the importlib?

Running in the main.py

```
import gin
import importlib

gin.parse_config_file('config.gin')
module = importlib.import_module('src.external.SomeModule')
_class = getattr(module, 'SomeClass')

This is the externally defined module in src.external.SomeModule
@gin.configurable
SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable
```

This is the 'config.gin' file

```
SomeClass.variable=0
```

However if we define it this way, we get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_test.py", line 291, in <module>
    gin.parse_config_file(args.config_path)
  File "/site-packages/gin/config.py", line 1599, in parse_config_file
    parse_config(f, skip_unknown=skip_unknown)
  File "/site-packages/gin/config.py", line 1517, in parse_config
    bind_parameter((scope, selector, arg_name), value)
  File "/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/site-packages/gin/utils.py", line 68, in try_with_location
    augment_exception_message_and_reraise(exception, _format_location(location))
  File "/site-packages/gin/utils.py", line 49, in augment_exception_message_and_reraise
    six.raise_from(proxy.with_traceback(exception.__traceback__), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/site-packages/gin/utils.py", line 66, in try_with_location
    yield
  File "/site-packages/gin/config.py", line 1517, in parse_config
    bind_parameter((scope, selector, arg_name), value)
  File "/site-packages/gin/config.py", line 643, in bind_parameter
    pbk = ParsedBindingKey(binding_key)
  File "/site-packages/gin/config.py", line 508, in __new__
    raise ValueError("No configurable matching '{}'.".format(selector))
ValueError: No configurable matching 'src.data.SomeModule.SomeClass'.
  In file "config/cnn_test.gin", line 35
    src.external.SomeModule.SomeClass.variable=0.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to move the `gin.parse_config_file('config.gin')` to after your imports. According to the gin [README](https://github.com/google/gin-config)

> Finally, after defining or importing all configurable classes or functions, parse your config file to bind your configurations...

Try this:

```
module = importlib.import_module('src.external.SomeModule')
_class = getattr(module, 'SomeClass')
gin.parse_config_file('config.gin')
```